# How can I use Keras with webcam?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have an pretrained model. Model trained with 20000 "gray" sample. İt is working with "gray" test samples. But I want to test this model with webcam. Here my code:

```
#Load the saved model
model = keras.models.load_model('C:\keras\handrecognition_model.h5')
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = video.read()
    im = Image.fromarray(frame, 'RGB')
    im = im.resize((128, 128))
    img_array = np.array(im)

    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)

    prediction = int(model.predict(img_array)[0][0])

    # if prediction is 0, which means I am missing on the image, then show the frame in gray color.
    if prediction == 0:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
            break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

There is an error : ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (120, 320, 1) but got array with shape (128, 128, 3).

Here output of gray test images:
[image]

Model trained:

```
# Construction of model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(120, 320, 1))) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Edit: I update code like this:

```
_, frame = video.read()
frame = cv2.resize(frame, (120, 360))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_array = np.array(gray)
```

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 360, 120)

Edit 2: Here train article:
https://towardsdatascience.com/tutorial-using-deep-learning-and-cnns-to-make-a-hand-gesture-recognition-model-371770b63a51

Edit 3: I guess, it is working. Now I will send frame to predict and I will found hand gest. I will share if I can do. Thank you.

```
    _, frame = video.read()
    frameCopy=frame.copy()
    frameCopy = cv2.resize(frameCopy, (120, 320))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frameCopy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_array = np.array(gray)
    img_array = img_array.reshape(120, 320, 1)
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
```

Comment: You need to reshape your input to the network's input shape before feeding it to the network.

Comment: As I understand my input shape is (120, 320, 1). I can resize as 128,128 but I couldn't change colour scale.

Comment: Your webcam image is `(128, 128, 3)`. You need to convert it to grayscale and resize/pad it to the right shape.

Comment: Can I share the link to train article? Is it forbidden?

Comment: It's not forbidden, just add it to the question if you think it helps understanding what you're trying to do

Comment: Actually, my question is simple. How do I use the model in the article with pictures from the camera? It's a really important problem for me. I will be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for you question after your edit:**
You need 4 dimensions not three: (batch-size, channels, width, height). So try the following:

```
img_array = np.array(gray)
img_array = img_array.reshape(1, 1, 360, 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    im = Image.fromarray(frame, 'RGB')
    im = im.resize((128, 128))
    im = im.convert('RGB')
```

This will convert your grayscale image to RGB. It will just copy the values from the one dimension you currently have to 3 dimensions. If it throws an error,
try this instead

```
    im = im.convert('L')
    im = im.convert('RGB')
```

`'L'` converts it to black and white first in case your input is sometimes not just 1D

Comment: I already tried "L" but I am still taking same error. All train and test sample gray scale. But I want to test this model from camera. I added a link. It maybe helps.